# Configuring VLAN on Juniper EX2200 switches

Tags: juniper, junos, switch

I have a Juniper EX2200-24T switch.It is configured as an L2 switch (i.e the interfaces are configured in such way that they do not have an IP address.).I have manually connected the port ge-0/0/0 of the Switch to my PC eth0 port.

I want to create a simple VLAN on the switch and make that the default L3 interface and be able to ping the swtich from the PC.

I am doing the following commands from the Junos CLI.

1) edit (To enter configuration mode)

2) edit interfaces (Mode to add interfaces to vlans)

3) set get-0/0/1 unit 0 family ethernet-switching vlan members myvlan

4) edit vlans

5) set myvlan interface get-0/0/1.0

6) edit interfaces vlan

7) set unit 100 family inet address 192.168.1.1/32

8) edit vlans

9) set myvaln vlan-id 100

10) set myvlan l3-interface vlan.100

I am able to commit the above changes.But I still cannot ping the IP 192.168.1.1 from the PC.It would be great if anyone can point out to me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You plugged into port 0/0/0 but configured port 0/0/1, that's your issue.